# Unknown crash with little stack trace

Tags: android, realm

I have been working on a new app that syncs tickets with a database periodically. However for the last few day's have been trying to track down the following error but currently I am not even sure where i should be looking.

The problem occurs at random and on multiple devices. Also using realm.io for the local database (not sure if that is relevant to the problem but have never seen this issue before I started using Realm)

```
E/art: Tried to mark 0x469d469c not contained by any spaces
E/art: Attempting see if it's a bad root
E/art: Found invalid root: 0x469d469c 
E/art: Type=RootThreadObject thread_id=1179862610
E/art: Found invalid root: 0x468b468a 
E/art: Type=RootNativeStack thread_id=1179862610
E/art: Found invalid root: 0x46a546a4 
E/art: Type=RootVMInternal thread_id=0
E/art: Found invalid root: 0x46a746a6 
E/art: Type=RootVMInternal thread_id=0
E/art: Found invalid root: 0x46b346b2 
E/art: Type=RootNativeStack thread_id=1179862610
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This does not look like a Realm related bug, see e.g this on the Google bug tracker: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=147187

Answer (score 0):

This a bug is in a native library which related to realm.io .so files or probably other library that use native code in your app.

Comment: Could you please provide a source?